# Unexpected end of input in ui-bootstrap file

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I get this error whenever I load the page I am building. Everything worked fine until I copied the angular-ui-bootstrap js file. I have not changed anything from the file.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.datepicker').run(function() {
!angular.$$csp().noInlineStyle && angular.element(document).find('head').prepend('<style type="text/css">.uib-  datepicker .uib-title{width:100%;}.uib-day button,.uib-month button,.uib-year button{min-width:100%;}.uib-datepicker-popup.dropdown-menu{display:block;}.uib-button-bar{padding:10px 9px 2px;}</style>');});
```

This is the portion of code where it has a missing } but that is not the case as I can see. I am running AngularJS 1.4.9 and Bootstrap 3.3.2.

Any ideas?

update: When I change to Angular 1.4.0 I get
 $q.resolve is not a function error

full error

```
TypeError: $q.resolve is not a function
at http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:46792:32
at Object.forEach (http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:350:20)
at Object.resolve (http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:46790:19)
at Object.$modal.open (http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:47357:69)
at Scope.$scope.open (http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:46443:35)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:13036:15), <anonymous>:4:203)
at callback (http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:23090:17)
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:15719:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:15818:23)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/build/js/all-136a0f7ece.js:23095:23)
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-1.1.2.js:3538

Comment: I changed to Angular 1.4.0 then changed the q.resolve for q.when and that worked. Closing this.